# change list of value in dictionary to set

Tags: python, dictionary, types

I got a dictionary that has multiple value:

```
reversed_dict = {a:[1,2,3,4,5],b:[1,4,5,6],c:[2,3,4,5,6].....]
```

I am trying to change type of value in dictionary to {}

```
    reversed_dict = {a:{1,2,3,4,5},b:{1,4,5,6},c:{2,3,4,5,6}.....]
```

is there any function for do this in python?

this is the code that I used for make dictionary reversed_dict:

```
d = dict(zip(k, v))
d2 ={k + '.' + str(i): v[i] for k, v in d.items() for i in range(len(v))}
reversed_dict = {}
for value in d2.values():
    if value not in reversed_dict.keys():
        reversed_dict[value] = []
        for key in d2.keys():
            if d2[key] == value:
                if key not in reversed_dict[value]: reversed_dict[value].append(key)
return reversed_dict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this (a `dictionary` comprehension)

```
>>> {k: set(v) for k,v in reversed_dict.items()}
{'a': {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 'b': {1, 4, 5, 6}, 'c': {2, 3, 4, 5, 6} ...}
```

**Note:** A `set` is an unordered collection data type that is `iterable`, `mutable` and has no `duplicate` elements